# Python getting parent class function to child classes instance

Tags: python, class, parent

I want to have a function in my parent class that when called by child class it will create another instance of that child class. I have an ugly solution but there must be better one. Here is my solution (this is in the function within the parent class):

```
    if type(self) == MountainAsh:
        trees.append (MountainAsh(seedlingLocation,0)) #Adds new seedling to trees list
    elif type(self) == TeaTree:
        trees.append (TeaTree(seedlingLocation,0)) #Adds new seedling to trees list
```

A little more code for context: (feel free to give other pointers, I am new to this, particularly OOP approaches)

```
class Tree(): #Tree parent class 
    def __init__(self, location, age):
        self.location = location #tuple (x,y)
        self.age = age
        self.fertility = .5 #fertility betweeen 0 and 1
        self.seedRange = 3 #Range from tree that seed can land
        self.shade = 1 #Shade preventing new seedlings
        self.lifeSpan =10 #tree dies at this age (no random currently)
        
    def reproduce(self):
        if random.uniform(0,1)<self.fertility: #Does it produce a seed?
            distance = random.uniform(0,self.seedRange)  #random range
            angle = random.uniform(0,2*math.pi) #random sirection
            #calculation of seed location
            seedlingLocation = (self.location[0]+distance*math.cos(angle),self.location[0]+distance*math.sin(angle))
            if seedlingLocation[0]>forestSize[0] or seedlingLocation[1]>forestSize[1] or min(seedlingLocation)<0:
                return #checking if seed falls outside of forest therefore it doesn't grow
            for i in trees:
                if math.dist(i.location,seedlingLocation)<i.shade: #Checking if seed is outside of shade of existing tress
                    return
            if type(self) == MountainAsh:
                trees.append (MountainAsh(seedlingLocation,0)) #Adds new seedling to trees list
            elif type(self) == TeaTree:
                trees.append (TeaTree(seedlingLocation,0)) #Adds new seedling to trees list

#set up long lived tree
class MountainAsh(Tree):
    def __init__(self, location, age):
        super().__init__(location, age)
        self.fertility = 0.3 #lower fertility
        self.seedRange = 3 #larger
        self.shade = 1 
        self.lifeSpan =15 #longer lived

#set up short lived tree
class TeaTree(Tree):
    def __init__(self, location, age):
        super().__init__(location, age)
        self.fertility = 0.8 #high fertility
        self.seedRange = 2 #smaller
        self.shade = .5 
        self.lifeSpan =5 #Short lived
```

Comment: If `type(self)` is `TeaTree` (for example), then you can use that expression wherever you'd use `TeaTree` directly - and the same thing applies to every subclass type.  So `type(self)(seedlingLocation, 0)` would make your desired new instance of the same subclass.

Comment: It's not clear in your code where trees is defined (is it a global?). But it doesn't seem like a single tree instance should be tasked with mutating that or even know about it.

Comment: Thank you trees.append (type(self)(seedlingLocation,0))